# Air core solenoid Melting when given 3amps with neodymium magnets as core

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm currently using magnets and ferrofluid in an art project. I'm not experienced with electrical engineering but maybe that will be obvious after reading this question.

I'm currently using this air core solenoid

https://www.schoolspecialty.com/science-first-air-core-solenoid-532015?gclid=CjwKCAjwyMfZBRAXEiwA-R3gM5FUxM-X6lp6yX7O-YWdqZLMyAb1wgY1hNIZ70pZ9scEdL1RDXTGBRoCHm0QAvD_BwE

hooked up to this power adapter [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B078RY7BPL/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078RY7BPL)

The power adapter outputs 3 Amps and the air core solenoid supposedly can take 5 amps. The positive terminal was hooked directly to the power adapter and the negative terminal was hooked up to a relay which in turn was connected to the power adapter.

Inside the core I have a stack of 20 neodymium magnets found here

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071ZKQ2X5/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071ZKQ2X5)

I have a sensor hooked up to an arduino that turns the relay on and off based on input. This makes the strength of the magnets inside the core increase and decrease in power based on whether the power supply is turned on.

In this sense it actually works great. Unfortunately it ended up heating up so much the plastic inside the solenoid melted.

Is there something wrong? Do I need to supply it with a weaker power supply? Does it have to do with the power of my magnets?

Answer (score 3):

You have a power supply rated at 3A maximum, however you did not do anything to limit the current to the coil. There is no guarantee that you didn't draw considerably more than 3A from the power supply (overloading it and the coil).

To limit the current you would need at least something like a series resistor, or you could use a lab power supply in current limit mode. In any case you should measure the current to ensure you are not exceeding the maximum.

We are assuming here that the coil is actually capable of handling 5A continuous, but that may not in fact be true. It's possible it does not meet the stated specification, but without a measurement it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Using ohm's law, I'm getting that the number of Ohms I would need would be 24(v) / 3(a) but that just equals 8. And an 8 ohm resistor doesn't seem right.

Comment: Went ahead and got an 8 ohm resistor rated for 100W

Comment: Should be minimum 8 ohms minus the resistance of the coil, but 8 ohms will be safe. Worst-case power dissipation is 24^2/8 = 72W, so 100W rating should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you’re using Fine wire that has a resistance more than eight ohms otherwise you would be current limiting.

But in any case the “Ampacity” of that wire (look up) depends on the free convection cooling of a straight wire , not confined to a small coil space so you’re clearly overloading it.

Try a high velocity  fan but beware the magnetic field will load ( interfere with) the fan motor so use a longer shaft.

What you have is not an air coil, but a speaker without the diaphragm.